# ssh clients hang after authentication and must be killed

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ssh, linux-networking

After installing a new router I'm experiencing some very strange problems using SSH clients.

The ssh command hangs after successful authentication. Here's the last output of the client's detailed debug output.

```
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
```

Here's the debug1:

```
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_GB.UTF-8
```

I cannot Ctrl-C to get out of this; the client must be killed, e.g. `pkill ssh`

Strangely, if on the same Ubuntu client machine I fire up a VirtualBox running Debian, I am able to SSH to the same server(s) from within the vm without a problem. I would have thought that this would have also failed since it's essentially the same client sending the same traffic.

Everything points to the router or the ISP as these are the things that have changed, but I've never come across this behaviour before.

Most posts here seem to focus on dodgy shell config, but nothing there has changed, and I am able to use the SSH if I route it through a 4G dongle, for instance, so it's not that.

I'm flummoxed, can you help?

FWIW, the client machine is on Ubuntu 17.10, using `OpenSSH_7.5p1 Ubuntu-10ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016`. The router is a TP-Link VR2600 router using a FTTC line provided by PlusNet.

Comment: Have you tried this? Seems like a similar problem. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302677/ssh-does-not-respond-only-from-ubuntu

Comment: @kasperd Agree. closing/deleting